# Estimating SQL Transition from 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to estimate a project to convert a SQL Server 2000 database with database replication to SQL Server 2008.  Anyone have thoughts on how I can estimate the level of effort to perform the conversion?  I'm thinking of outsourcing the task so that I have the expertise of someone that's been through this before.  I would like to estimate and budget for the project, but I'm not sure of how big of a task this is really going to be.

Comment: Are talking about programming changes to an application that runs against the database, or just updating the database itself?

Comment: As-is, too vague for anyone to provide a decent answer.

Answer (score 3):

Running the [SQL server upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=F5A6C5E9-4CD9-4E42-A21C-7291E7F0F852&displaylang=en) should provide a good overview of what changes will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the 490 page long [SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Technical Reference Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=66D3E6F5-6902-4FDD-AF75-9975AEA5BEA7) to get some idea of the work involved. Of course, not all 490 pages will be relevant for your case, but many chapters are of interest, like *4.7 Upgrading Replicated Databases* or *8. T-SQL Queries*. You don't have to read through all the paper and become an expert yourself, but you can use the paper to specify your job requirements and to judge the quality of the offers you get.